# How to use the User ID to kick,ban and unban a user

Tags: discord.py

I just learned how to code a discord bot with python.

Ban command

```
@bot.command()
async def ban(ctx, member: Member = None, *, reason):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
```

Kick command

```
@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: Member = None, *, reason):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
```

Unban command

```
@bot.command()
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')
    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user

        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
```

But how can I use the User ID to kick,ban and unban someone?

Comment: Have you tried with the code you have?  The Member converter should be able to use the id to resolve the `Member` object

Answer (score 0):

If member is on server, you can normal ban/kick by ID
If member isn't on server, you must use `await client.fetch_user(ID).ban`